# flutter localization rtl ltr change for some widgets but not for some other

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I'm changing my app to a multi lingual app and I'm using Applocalizations package from pub dev.
I have extracted all the UI strings and put them into .arb files also did the translated .arb files.
Now when I change locale to some language which is rtl like Arabic some widgets get mirrored even margins and paddings get mirror effect but others stay the way they are.
The obvious solution popped to my head was to do a simple if statement for every such case which did not get mirrored.
But I would like to know if there is a better way to fix this and why some widgets get mirrored some does not.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:
You have to use directional alignment and EdgeInsets so the app would flip on locale changes.

```
EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start:30,end:30) not EdgeInsets.only(right:30,left:30)
```

for more help you can visit [here](https://leancode.co/blog/right-to-left-in-flutter-app).

Answer (score 0):

make sure you added

```
                GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
```

in the localizationsDelegates list in the main method

Answer (score 0):

You can use **EdgeinsetsDirectional** to be able to shared the alignment and spaces respecting each language direction

> EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(top: AmpSpacing.spacingXXS)